# Why are my single select lists converting to multi select lists on model binding?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to bind multiple single select lists to one list of strings in my view model I have the property: `public List<string> Items {get; set;}` and in my view I have 3 select lists with single select option, but when I try to model bind my select list to Items property using `asp-for="@Model.Items"` all my single select lists converts to multi select lists. Why?

My view:

```
<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label>Order By Price:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Items" style="width:150px">
                        <option value="Ascending">Ascending</option>
                        <option value="Descending">Descending</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label>Order By Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Items"  style="width:150px">
                        <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
                        <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(MangeProductsViewModel vm)
        {
            return View(new MangeProductsViewModel
            {
                Products = productRepository.Products.ToList().SortProducts(vm)
            });
        }
```

My viewmodel

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
public List<string> Items { get; set; }
```

And when I select items from lists it adds them correctly the problem is dat user can select multiple options from one list

Comment: please share html code snippet of select list generated

Comment: I added code for my view and controller

Answer (score 0):

That's because `asp-for` invokes a tag helper, and for a prop of type `List<string>`, the HTML that is generated is going to be a select multiple. However, this wouldn't work for you *anyways* as it would give all the selects the same name. As a result, they'll simply overwrite each other, not add to each other.

For this, you're going to have to handle things manually via:

```
<select name="Items[]">
    @foreach (var option in Model.SelectList1Options)
    {
        <option value="@option.Value">@option.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

For each drop down.

Comment: Well you are wrong about overwriting because it adds values to the list the problem is dat user can select multi options from the lists

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

In your HttpGet method create a new list with length 3 and assign it to Items property of model and pass the model to view.

And in view write asp-for as follows

> asp-for=“@Model.Items[0]”
>
> asp-for=“@Model.Items[1]”
>
> asp-for=“@Model.Items[2]”

Comment: There is no dinamic option? Couz what if latter on I add new select lists I need manually change arrays size

Comment: Then I guess you need to control the multi select behaviour at client side only.

Comment: Even now you are fixing the number of selects in your view. Later if you want to add more selects then you have to edit your view

Comment: Yes but It would be one less edit I wanna make my code as easy to extend as possible

Comment: then drive the limit from app settings

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have used `asp-for="@Model.Items"`, sicne your item is type of  `List<string>`, so the dropdown list is set as multiple select.

Just use `name="Items"` instead:

```
<form asp-controller="Managers" asp-action="SelectTest" method="post">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label>Order By Price:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <select class="form-control" name="Items" style="width:150px">
                        <option value="Ascending">Ascending</option>
                        <option value="Descending">Descending</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <label>Order By Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <select class="form-control" name="Items" style="width:150px">
                        <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
                        <option value="Z-A">Z-A</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]